# Theorem on residue of composite function

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, residue-calculus

The following interesting and useful statement was [reported](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2830152) some time ago on MSE:

$$
\underset{z=g(a)}{\operatorname{Res}}f(z)=\underset{z=a}{\operatorname{Res}}f(g(z))g'(z),\tag1
$$
provided that $g(z)$ is analytic in the neighborhood of $a$ and $g'(a)\ne0$.

I looked through several textbooks on complex analysis but have not found any mention of the statement. Was this result ever published?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. You will find it, for instance, on Reinhold Remmert's *Theory of Complex Functions*. He calls it “transformation rule for residues”. It's on chapter 13, section 1.